# $L=\left\{v:q_1\left(v\right) \ge q_2\left(v\right)\right\}$ is a subspace of $V$.Show that $q_1 \ge q_2 \:or\: q_2 \ge q_1 \forall v\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

$V=\mathbb{R^n}$

$q_1,q_2:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ are quadratic forms.

$L=\left\{v \in \mathbb{R^n}:q_1\left(v\right) \ge q_2\left(v\right)\right\}$  is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Show that $\forall v \in \mathbb{R^n}, q_1(v) \ge q_2(v) \:or\: q_2(v) \ge q_1(v)$

My approach:

What I actually need to show is that if we mark $q=q_1 - q_2$, then $q$ is positive definite or $q$ is negative definite.
I assume by contradiction that $q$ is neither of the above options, I somehow wants to get to a contradiction to the fact that $L$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Quadratic Forms Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931683/two-quadratic-forms-inequality) (which was asked (by me) more recently than this question, but it has an answer, unlike this one).