# Two Quadratic Forms Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Given two quadratic forms, $q_1, q_2: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and the fact that the following set is a ***linear** subspace* of $\mathbb{R}^n$,

$$L = \{v\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid q_1(v)\geq q_2(v)\}$$

We have to prove that either of these statements hold:
$$
\text{1.}\quad \forall v(v\in \mathbb{R}^n \to q_1(v)\geq q_2(v)) \\
\text{or}\\
\text{2.}\quad \forall v(v\in \mathbb{R}^n \to q_1(v)\leq q_2(v)) 
$$

It's easy to prove statement $1$ holds iff $L=\mathbb{R}^n$. 
So, assuming $L\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$, we have to prove that statement $2$ is true.

I've tried defining a new quadratic form 
$$p = q_1 - q_2$$
and then proving by contradiction that $p(v) \leq 0 \space \text{for each}\space v\in\mathbb{R}^n $, but I couldn't develop this further.

Can you provide some insight about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we basically want to show that $L$ is a trivial subspace.

So if $p$ is your quadratic form, first put it into [diagonal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms).

Then the diagonal matrix representing the form has some positive and some negative eigenvalues (if it has only positive/negative eigenvalues, we are done since $p$ is definite).

Let $e$ be an eigenvector corresponding to a positive eigenvalue and $f$ corresponding to a negative one (so $e \in L$ but $f \notin L$).

Also, let $B$ be the bilinear form corresponding to $p$.

Then for any real $t$,
\begin{align*}
p(e+tf) &= B(e+tf,e+tf) \\
&= B(e,e) + B(e,tf) + B(tf,e) + B(tf,tf) \\
&= B(e,e) + 2tB(e,f) + t^2B(f,f) \\
&= B(e,e)+t^2B(f,f) \\
&= p(e)+t^2p(f)
\end{align*}

$B(e,f)=0$ since the matrix is symmetric (or more generally, normal), so the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Now $p(e)$ is positive and $p(f)$ is negative by definition. But if we let $t \downarrow 0$ then $p(e+tf) > 0$, meaning $e+tf$ belongs to $L$, which shouldn't happen. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Just a quick note - no need to actually diagonalize the matrix (it is not possible anyway, since $q_1,q_2$ are unknown), it is only worth noting that it is symmetric and therefore diagonalizable by a unitary matrix